# Differences in order of stderr and stdout generates a problem

Tags: unix, sh, ksh, aix

In [AIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX), when I write a script like this (*test.sch*):

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "testing" 2>./r1.log 1>./r2.log
exit 0
```

If I execute:

```
sh -x test.sch
```

The response is:

```
cat r1.log
1> ./r2.log
cat r2.log
testing
```

Why does the *r1.log* appear part of the command?

But if I change the order in the shell:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "testing" 1>./r2.log 2>./r1.log
exit 0
```

The file *r1.log* is empty:

```
cat r1.log
cat r2.log
```

Output:

```
testing
```

This code works fine on another server. What configuration must I fix to make it work?

## Summary

I can't omit the `-x` flag, because I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (this uses `-x`). But I realize that the error is happening on different AIX servers. I guess that there is not a solution, except changing the order of the output.

Comment: What actually the problem is? `set -x` is a debugging feature, its output might very well be platform-dependent.

Comment: I would expect `r1.log` to be empty in both cases, since `echo` isn't writing anything to standard error. I have no idea where the `cat ... `  lines are coming from, since your script doesn't run `cat` at all.

Comment: Can't reproduce that problem using the provided script. The content of the log file won't change whichever the order. But the way you actually invoke the -x option makes your shell (sh ?) in debug mode, not ksh which is the shell used to run your script. If you want to debug your script you should add set -x right after the shebang in your script.

Comment: @OP: Simply drop the `-x` part from the command: `sh test.sch`.

Answer (score 0):

`set -x` (or the corresponding `sh -x`, short for "xtrace") switches on debug mode. Debug mode prints out every line executed to [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). From [the AIX man page of](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=k-ksh-command) [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell) (executable `ksh`):

```
-x
     Prints executed commands and their arguments.
```

This is why you see something in the log file which captures standard error.